# Find second last row from table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with dynamic row and I want to find second last row from table.

**HTML Code**

```
<table class="table">   
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
alert($(".table").find("tr:last").find("td").html());
```

I tried with `tr:last` but it give me last row with value `10`.

**Expected Output**

Second last row value `9` instead of `10`

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eccatx66/)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `.prev()` to go back one element.

```
alert($(".table tr:last").prev().find("td").html());
```

Answer (score 6):

With nth-last-child:

```
alert($(".table").find("tr:nth-last-child(2)").find("td").html());
```

You could also make it a single selector:

```
alert($(".table tr:nth-last-child(2) td").html());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var total = $(".table").find("tr").length;
alert($(".table").find("tr:nth-child("+(total-1)+")").find("td").html());
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eccatx66/1/)

Answer (score 2):

use .eq() and -1 is specifies the last element ...

```
alert($(".table").find("tr").eq(-2).find("td").html());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.table tr:last').prev('tr').html()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

`alert($(".table").find("tr:last").prev().find("td").html());`

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eccatx66/)

Answer (score 0):

Second Last Row Remove

```
$('tbody tr:last', $("#ctl00_MainContent_rdgImgDig_ctl00")).prev().remove();
```

Comment: The user is not asking to remove the row, but to select it with jQuery, also please remove the reference to `#ctl00_MainContent_rdgImgDig_ctl00` which is not mentioned anywhere in the question.